# What is the python script for the Rip tool

Tags: python

What is the python script to do a rip tool (V key) without moving the components after separating the components.

Comment: could you provide your .blend file with your script? Also add screenshots showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the below script
2. Select an edge
3. Hit the spacebar and write "Rip Edge" as shown below

[image]

```
import bpy
bl_info = {
    "name": "Rip Edge",
    "category": "Edit",
}

class EdgeRip(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Rip Edge"""
    bl_idname = "edit.ripedge"
    bl_label = "Rip Edge"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.rip('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(EdgeRip)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(EdgeRip)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: I have just copy/pasted your script with import bpy on top in the text editor and run the script after selecting an edge. Does it work for you?

Comment: It won't work that way, you need to put it in an operator and call this operator

Comment: @DanylBekhoucha answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for your script but i want a minimal code to integrate inside my current script.

Comment: Well, I don't know your current script, but this is the line doing what you want bpy.ops.mesh.rip('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

Comment: if i use this command the script doesn't compile.

Comment: @DanylBekhoucha Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?

Comment: Hi, it's upvoted already but not marked as solved because i want to use one line to integrate in my current script and the one you given doesn't compile.

Comment: @DanylBekhoucha you are still facing the same problem? If so, you can share your whole script and I'll have a look

Comment: I will redo my script and use the rip tools to detach meshes based on sharp edges, refill faces and create bevel to generate stylized assets in one click for "Blender Game Tools" ( https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?383624-Dark-Blender-(Official-Thread)-optimized-for-sculpting-and-game-asset-creation&p=3133941&viewfull=1#post3133941 ). But for know this simple script doesn't compile after selecting an edge:

import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.rip('INVOKE_DEFAULT')